# Can't Use Newly Created User to Run Postgres createdb Command

Tags: postgresql, linux

**Short Version:**

I get:

> error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"

when I try to `createdb --username admin --password mynewdb` ... but I created the "admin" user in both Linux and PostgreSQL, so I don't understand why I can't use them.

**Long Version:**

I am trying to create an "admin" user to run SQL on a brand new Ubuntu/AWS machine.  I created the user with

```
$ sudo useradd -g admin admin
```

Then I set their password using:

```
$ sudo passwd admin
```

I know the password was set correctly, because I can switch to the "admin" user by typing that password in, with:

```
$ su - admin
```

I also created a database role for the user, with:

```
CREATE ROLE admin WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'samepassword';
```

and I can see that the user was created with `\du` (from inside `psql`):

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

Furthermore, I can confirm, from my `pg_hba.conf` file, that Postgres should use the "peer" (ie. system) password for that user:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

And I restarted Postgres, just to be safe:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

However, despite all of the above, when I try to create a new database with that "admin" user, using `createdb`, I get prompted for my password, twice, and then it fails:

```
$ createdb --username admin --password mynewdb
Password: 
Password: 
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed:
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"
```

I've tried reading other SO answers for this error, but they all suggest things I've tried (ie. changing `pg_hba.conf`, restarting Postgres, etc.)  But, I'm sort of a Postgres newb, so if anyone has any further suggestions I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone over on Stack Overflow helpfully explained, it's not enough to just add the  `--username admin` argument; you also have to be logged-in (in your operating system) as that user.